# Is it possible to have two different domains accessing the same MySql database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create two different website on different domains and I wanted to connect to the same database so that I can access the data on both site. Is there a possibility to do this fuction as I am using Laravel FW.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, in the .env / config, use the same database settings for both.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried to define two database in the env file and google help but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you have hosted 2 domain in same server then you can use as much as you want.
if you have hosted in different server then you have probably two options:

1. You must allow remote connection for each script IP
2. You can create API to use for different server